# Why method in JAVA source code calls another method even though calling method just do a call job?

Tags: java

When I was reading source code of LinkedList, I find a strange phenomenon(Maybe starnge just to me....) that many public method do nothing else but only call another private method like below.

```
public void addFirst(E e) {
    linkFirst(e);
}
public void addLast(E e) {
    linkLast(e);
}
```

Thus, could anybody tell me why method should be written like this, thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe these methods are being called from elsewhere as well.

Comment: Often this is done in classes that implement multiple interfaces and want to prevent duplicate code

Answer (score 0):

As [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8819761/jeroen-steenbeeke) comments, this is often done to avoid writing multiple methods that do the same thing when a class is implementing (directly or indirectly) multiple interfaces, and the interfaces methods have overlapping semantics.

But in this case, `linkFirst` and `linkLast` are internal methods.  Here, the reason appears to be that the code has been reorganized, and this is consequence of that reorganization.  The Java 6 source code implements these methods as follows:

```
public void addFirst(E e) {
    addBefore(e, header.next);
}

public void addLast(E e) {
    addBefore(e, header);
}
```

Does it matter?  Is it inefficient?

Probably not.  The JIT compiler is likely inline the `addFirst` and `addLast` methods wherever they are called.  But even if it doesn't the overhead of the unnecessary call will be tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Methods `addFirst(E e)` & `addLast(E e)` are both required, as `java.util.LinkedList` implements the interface `java.util.Deque` where these 2 methods are specified.

Nowadays, you would use the `@Override` annotation on those 2 implementations to indicate you know that to the compiler, but back then when much of this code was written annotations weren't that widespread (or even invented?).
(Annotations first became publicly available in JDK 1.5)

Now, `linkFirst(E e)` is private & only called from `addFirst(E e)`, so maybe you could argue it could be inlined, but maybe someone decided it would be prudent to protect that logic as `addFirst(E e)` is public & may be subclassed.

`linkLast(E e)` has default visibility & is called from many places, so it may be invoked from other members in the `java.util` package, but again it may have been deemed prudent to not expose this logic as `addLast(E e)` may be subclassed.